# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. while publishing dev code to production

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am working on the provider hosted app and tried to publish my development code to production i am getting the following error

while publishing the code to production i have changed the client id and secret of production in web .config
changed the client id in appmanifest.xml i got the error as invalid jwt token issue then i have created a new client secret then appended into dev code and published to production publishing profile .after publishing the code if i try to open tha app i am getting the error as displayed on the image .
needed to help to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fsBp.png)